# How to redirect crontab output from mail to stdout

Tags: cron

I have created script that runs a command that uses printf to print to the stdout. I have set the script up on a crontab to run every minute. Everything works fine, except that the output is sent to mail every time. Is there a way to just have the output pop up on the stdout every minute?

I have tried some redirecting to &1 in the shell script, but that has not worked.

```
* * * * * cd ~/Desktop/tools && ./remind.sh
```

As I said, the output is mailed to me, and does not simply show up in stdout every minute.

Comment: What do you mean by "to stdout"? Your script writes to stdout, and stdout in this case is connected to the mail system. That's how cron works.

Comment: I guess I was trying to use crontab as a way to execute the command and print to stdout multiple times. I wanted the results of the script to show up in the terminal window every minute. Is there a different tool I should be using?

Comment: It is printing to stdout. "stdout" does not mean terminal. What do you mean by "the terminal window", by the way? What if you have 10 terminal windows? Or none of them?

Comment: "Is there a different tool I should be using?" I think you should write an application which uses sleep() to control its periodic output to STDOUT. If necessary, you can execute it in the background wit '&' at the end of the command line.

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect output to syslog with **logger**:

`* * * * * cd ~/Desktop/tools && ./remind.sh 2>&1 | logger`